# How to pass array of objects in a method as the object array is defined privately in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arguments

First Class

```
public Class Student {
private int roll;
private String name; }
//getter & setter methods for both
```

Second Class

```
public Class StudentData {
private Student s [] = new Student[3];
public void addStudent(Student s[]) {
//method to add Student Data

public class TestStudent {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentData sd = new StudentData();
    sd.addStudent(**What should be passed as parametet here??**);
```

How arguments to be passed in sd.addStudent(?)

Comment: A different array of students?

Comment: Methods and variables added as per question. Since Student array is declared as private in StudentData, don't know what argument should be passed

Comment: Neither do we, given that we have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Also please refer to this page before posting any more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your `StudentData` could contain only 3 object maximum. I offer you to use List instead. In this case your class could look like this:

```
public final class StudentData {
    private final Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();

    public void addStudents(Student[] students) {
        if (students != null && students.length > 0)
            for (Student student : students)
                addStudent(student);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        if (student != null)
            students.put(student.getName(), student);
    }
}
```

Add whole array to the `StudentData` brakes incapsulation. You have to accept array and add each element separately (see example above).

Anyway you could add any methods to the `StudentData` you need: for single elemnts, add this element; for collection or array, add all elements separately ineratingh through the collection.

**P.S.** Example (only for example) without collection:

```
public final class StudentData {
    private final Student[] students;
    private int pos;

    public StudentData(int max) {
        students = new Student[max];
    }

    public void addStudents(Student[] students) {
        if (students != null && students.length > 0)
            for (Student student : students)
                addStudent(student);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        if (student != null) {
            if (pos >= students.length) {
                // array is full
            } else {
                students[pos++] = student;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! But this question came into my class before we started learning Collections. Any chance, i could solve this without using List?

Comment: Yes sure. This is less convinient, but still. See example above. In in you should not foreget to decrement pos marker whe remove student.